# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, api, spring-boot

desde Spring Boot, creo un método handler que devuelve una lista de productos y quiero capturar esos datos desde `JavaScript` . Pero me sale el "error" colocado como titulo.

**Controlador**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/losProductos/{param}", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Product> productos(@PathVariable String param){
    return productService.findByName(param);
}
```

desde **JavaScript**:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/tiendamusical/losProductos/Guitarr';

  const options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  };
  async function fetchProductsJSON() {
    const response = await fetch(url, {mode:'no-cors'}, options);
    const producc = await response.json();
    return producc;
  }

  console.log(fetchProductsJSON())
```

Me sale este error:

> Promise { : "pending" }
> : "rejected"
> : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
> app.html:141:13
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Accedi a la ruta desde el navegador y si funciona, me devuelve el **JSON**

Comment: Por favor has un console.log de `producc` y de `response` y muestra que te logea

Comment: Recuerdo que `@ResponseBody` se utiliza para anotar el método al igual que `@GetMapping`, mueve la anotación y comentas si eso soluciona tu problema.